# How can I refactor this PHP array code

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a better way how to get the other element in an array in PHP?

Assume that `$a` definitely exists in the array.

```
$array = array('one','two');

if($a==$array[0]){
    $b = $array[1];
}else{
    $b = $array[0];
}
```

It seems like too much code for such a small thing.

EDIT: I am not seeking a Ternary syntax. I am seeking a function of some sort that will do this automatically.

EDIT2: I know one string. I know that there exists in the array that string and another. I want the other one. What PHP function can I use?

Comment: You're probably looking for one of the many [`array_diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) functions.

Comment: If `$array` always has 2 elements, use `$b = current(array_diff($array, array($a)));` and make every other developer cry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's guaranteed to be just an array with two elements, and $a is guaranteed to exist as a value in $array

```
$b = $array[1 - array_search($a, $array)];
```

Comment: I love this and hate this at the same time :-)

Comment: I know, it's horrible, and shouldn't be used in production code because it isn't intuitive and obvious

Comment: @InGodITrust, That's what you were looking for?  You've got to be kidding me... I suggest you take a good look at your structures.  I can't imagine this being useful in any real world situations.

Comment: @InGodITrust now go read what you posted initially. Which is clearer in its intent and easier to maintain in the future? Consider someone else reading the code, and then consider the [WTFs per minute](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/whos-your-coding-buddy.html).

Comment: @cbuckley - after reading your suggestion in the comments for the original post, I'd even consider my suggestion as intuitive :)

Comment: @Brad I have two possible sort values, `votes` & `created`. I force the sort value to exist in the array, and count the array. Therefore the code is very useful.

Comment: @InGodITrust, Useful until you add a sort option later on...

Comment: @Brad true, there I am afraid you are right. Thanks for the input anyway!

Comment: I'm almost tempted to come up with an array_flip() solution, just to see how obscure I can make a solution... but always assume that the next guy to have to read your code is a serial killer who knows your address

Comment: @MarkBaker would you not think there should be some kind of function for this? Or am I mad.

Comment: @InGodITrust, Of course there wouldn't be a function like this... not even in PHP!  You might as well be using a boolean for your sort, since you only have two options.  In fact, you could probably use a boolean for your array key.

Comment: @Brad why, because it is limited to the number of elements?

Comment: @In God I Trust - why should there be, most coders faced with a two-state logic would use Booleans, because they're a two-state datatype; arrays are an unlimited-state datatype, so shouldn't be constrained by two-state limits

Comment: @MarkBaker so my code in the question is the preferred method?

Comment: @In God I Trust - your code in the original question is much better; good coders don't seek to make their code obscure, but to make it instantly obvious to anybody else reading it.... the only problem with your original code is that it doesn't allow for new options

Comment: No partial credit for me >< telling me I missed it by a `1 -`, FML...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to shorten the syntax.

```
$b = ($a==$array[0]) ? $array[1] : $array[0];
```

Comment: Ok, but thats cheating. Sorry, I should have made myself clearer, is there no function to do such a thing automatically?

Comment: @InGodITrust, No function to read your mind and implement your logic automatically?  No, that doesn't exist.  What specifically were you expecting to see?  How would this function work?  What would it do?

Comment: Automatically set a value to the opposite value of the specified string. Ie give it the meaning of `$a` and it knows to give you the other value in the array

Comment: @InGodITrust, Sounds like you want an associative array.  `$myArray = array('one'=>'two');  echo $myArray['one'];`

Comment: That was my first thought!  Why not use an associative array.  I went with the assumption he was wanting something for more than two options.

Comment: See Edit2. Dont see how an associative array would help

Comment: @InGodITrust, Given your Edit2, I don't see how an associative array wouldn't help.  You just want to map values from one to the other, yeah?

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a function to do what you're describing, but if you're looking to shorten your code, and you don't want to use a ternary, then you can do this:

```
$array = array('one','two');

$b = $array[0];
if($a==$array[0])
  $b = $array[1];
```

This works if, as you stated, `$a` definitely exists in the array.

Comment: Minimal. I am looking to extract an element from an array based on knowing the other element.

Comment: eyes burning!!! no brakets!!! *cry* For the love of God make your code readable! :P

Comment: Updated my answer to include your input.

Comment: No brakets are ugly, bu otherways its ok

Comment: Yes, it's ugly, but I was trying to shave off a bit of room, like he's asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$b = $a == $array[0] ? $array[1] : $array[0] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming your array may be longer than just two elements, couldn't you just do a search?

`$b = $array[array_search($a, $array)];`

Comment: He's actually looking to make `$b` the opposite of `$a`, so this wouldn't quite work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay to make this even more ugly, here's my solution:

```
$b = $array[!array_search($a, $array)];
```